# Read and parse JSON data

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I'm new to c# and I tried to parse the JSON data from WSDL service.

Here is the code:

```
string cityjson = service.getcity(); 

/*
sample cityjson return
[{"City":"Alaminos","Province":"Pangasinan"},{"City":"Angeles","Province":"Pampanga"},{"City":"Antipolo","Province":"Rizal"}]
*/


using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(cityjson)))
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Location));
    Location locs = (Location)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

    Console.WriteLine(locs.Locations); // blank in console output.
}
```

and here is my datacontract code

```
[DataContract]
public class Location
{
    [DataMember]
    public String[] Locations;
}
```

when I do `console.WriteLine(cityjson);` it prints the whole json.

Comment: Can you post your sample json?

Comment: I already posted the sample json in the code, with comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# class is wrong.It should have two properties `City` and `Province`.And the `json` object is a `List` of `Location`s. And try to use `JSON.Net` to parse your `json` data.It's lightweight and easy to use.Also you could use available resources to convert `json` to C# types.

```
public class Location
{
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String Province { get; set; }
}

var t = "[{'City':'Alaminos','Province':'Pangasinan'},{'City':'Angeles','Province':'Pampanga'},{'City':'Antipolo','Province':'Rizal'}]";

var type = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Location>>(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Rewrite your code like this

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
Location locs = js.Deserialize<Location>(ms);
```

Comment: How about explaining your answer so that the OP can learn the concepts behind your answer?